# Cisco AnyConnect/Umbrella blocking macOS update

Tags: macos, software-update, big-sur

I hope someone can assist....

Cisco AnyConnect is blocking company Macs from seeing new Big Sur 11.6 update.

I need to provide that info to the Cisco support team to have that address whitelisted on their end.

Does anyone know where macOS updates downloads from?

Comment: I'd tell then not to block `http://swcdn.apple.com/`, `https://swscan.apple.com` and `https://swdist.apple.com/`, although there may be some others as well.

Answer (score 1):

The easy solution is to unblock 17.0.0.0/8 as one firewall rule.

Here are the details in official form.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210060

> If your firewall can only be configured with IP addresses, allow outbound connections to 17.0.0.0/8. The entire 17.0.0.0/8 address block is assigned to Apple.